# How to compile multiple *.java files

Tags: java

Someone gave me their code: several *.java files under same directory (src\eval\*.java). I guess they are multiple source code files in the same project.

When trying to compile (under windows), I typed

```
javac -sourcepath src\eval\AlnEval.java -d bin
```

but I get this error when doing so:

> javac: no source file.

---

Tried

```
javac src\eval\AlnEval.java
```

Many errors in compilation. Seems AlnEval.java uses several classes defined in other *.java files.

Comment: Does the code rely on external dependencies that need added to the classpath?

Comment: @Cody: That's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the classpath to include the external dependencies. If you have all the dependencies as jar files in a lib directory, for example, you can use

```
java -cp lib\* src\eval\*.java
```

This includes all the dependencies needed to compile the app.

Answer (score 1):

try below code

first go to your main src directory

```
javac -cp .;lib/<YOU_JARS>.jar -d bin  packA/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type `javac *.java` or better just use and IDE such as eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To compile multiple files in one go, you just do

```
javac src\eval\*.java
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd src/eval
$ javac *.java
```

100101010101