# How to import class from other java file?

Tags: java, compilation, package

I am trying to implement Stack which is in other java file named Stack.java where I have declared package p1;
And I have imported it to file where I am going to use it.
Whenever I try to run it gives me **package does not exist error**
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCwPp.jpg)

I think my syntax is correct.
But I am having trouble understanding how to compile a package and run a program using class present in package. I am using Windows Visual Studio Code on Windows OS. I am running the java program in windows terminal.

Comment: you can build them into the same jar or build one as an dependency - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846817/how-to-compile-multiple-java-files

Comment: Please include your formatted code in the post.